# Настройка nginx, smarty, использование одного php файла

Tags: nginx, php, smarty

Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста, настроить nginx так, чтобы при открытии ссылки без расширения открывался всегда один php файл.
Этот файл будет определять страницу, которую человек хочет посетить и указывать smarty названия шаблона.
Или, возможно, есть другие варианты для работы с smarty, не создавая для каждой стр. php файл?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name XXX;
    root XXX;
    index index.php;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        # настройки подключения к php-fpm
    }
}
```

всегда будет ссылаться на index.php в случае отсутствия файла, соответствующего переданному url.

Comment: а если нужно перенаправлять на index.php, даже если клиент ввел правильный путь другого файла, например, admin.php?

Comment: @duhon, а как вы тогда статику будете раздавать? Можно в обработчике локации .php подменять скрипт на index.php.

Comment: @Etki, а можно ли сделать так, чтобы когда путь был без расширения (без точки), тогда он использовал этот файл, а во всех остальных как обычно, сам файл?

Comment: @Mr_Epic, я сейчас не могу это гарантировать, но, насколько понимаю, в случае запроса что_угодно.php он отдаст именно этот файл,а не индекс.

Comment: @Etki, вроде получилось сделать, написал вот так:  
  
root   "%hostdir%";  
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;